# I can't stop node on begin contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I tried so much methods but i didn't stop the cats when begin contacts.Here is node moving method:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"cat" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
        SKSpriteNode *tempCat = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
        float actionDuration = 0.1;
        CGPoint offset = CGPointSubtract(_zombie.position, tempCat.position);
        CGPoint direction = CGPointNormalize(offset);
        CGPoint amountToMovePerSec = CGPointMultiplyScalar(direction, CAT_MOVE_POINTS_PER_SEC);
        CGPoint amountToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(amountToMovePerSec, actionDuration);
        node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x+amountToMove.x, node.position.y+amountToMove.y);
        _velocityCat = CGPointMultiplyScalar(direction, CAT_MOVE_POINTS_PER_SEC);

        [self rotateNode:tempCat toFace:_velocityCat rotateRadiansPerSec:CAT_ROTATE_RADIANS_PER_SEC];
```

How can I stop cat when begin contact?

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (enemyCategory | catsCategory)) {
        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"cat" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([contact.bodyA.node isEqual:node] || [contact.bodyB.node isEqual:node])
            {
                node.physicsBody = NO;
                SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:2];
                SKAction *catDie = [SKAction runBlock:^{
                    [node removeFromParent];
                }];
                SKAction *animation = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, catDie]];
                [self runAction:animation];
            }
        }];        NSLog(@"test 1");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerating over all cat nodes is not necessary since you can get the node involved in the contact from the SKPhysicsContact object. The following shows how to do that...

**EDIT:** you can change the cat node's name to prevent it from chasing the zombie

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (enemyCategory | catsCategory)) {
        SKNode *node = contact.bodyA.node;
        if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == catsCategory) {
            node = contact.bodyB.node;
        }
        // One way to stop the cat from chasing zombie is by changing its name
        node.name = @"not cat";
    }
}
```

Comment: So how cats stop with this codes?Cat contact works already.But how can i stop moving cat when it contact with enemy.

Comment: See my edits. Do you still want to remove the cat from the scene?